# Best way to automate running several MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, best-practices

We have several core db tables on our system and allow our employees access to these tables via views that just show them the data they need to see.

We created these views in a new db specific to the new user.  Creating all of these views requires running several mysql queries.

I would like to automate this process into a script, but feel there must be tools already out there that take a list of queries and run them.

Can anyone recommend any such tools or even any built-in features in mysql that could assist me here ?

Thanks!

Comment: "there must be tools already out there that take a list of queries and run them" You mean.. Like a script?

Answer (score 6):

Create a text file containing all your commands. Call it `newuser.sql`. Then when you want to set up a new user, let's call him `gaius`, you would simply do

```
$ cat newuser.sql|mysql --user=gaius --password=abc123 somedb
```

Obviously you could even create new users in a script, let's call it `newuser.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "create user '$1'@'%' identified by password('$2');"|mysql --user=root --password=secret
cat newuser.sql|mysql --user=$1 --password=$2 somedb
```

Then do

```
$ ./newuser.sh gaius abc123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cron jobs, also known as crontab, cron etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a view is nothing more than

```
create db.view as select ...
```

What do you want to automate here?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures

Perl

PHP (especially handy from web page)

GRANT access to each user down at the column level.  (As an alternative to VIEWs.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a GUI tool, such as [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)? It will allow you to run multiple MySQL statements.

Other GUI tools are:
[DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/)
[PhpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)